# SSL: is it possible to use a certificate for a specific subdomain and a wilcard for all other sub domain?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a domain, say domain.com.

I have some random subdomains which all point to the same server. (eg: `user-00.domain.com`, `user-01.domain.com`, etc.)

I also have some fixed sub domain names, let's say `fixed.domain.com` which also point on the same server, but into docker containers.

My server is a docker machine:

- I have `certbot` installed as a native application (non dockerised). This certbot handle the wildcard certificate for all the random subdomains
- I have a container which handles the  certificate for the fixed domain with letsencrypt.

If I renew one of the fixed certificate, could there be any "merging" issue with the wildcard one? (and vis-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can have multiple certificates which match a domain at the same time, i.e. certificates for same subject with overlapping validity times, certificates with different but overlapping subjects/SAN ... . All what matters is the specific certificate which is served when connecting to a specific server, i.e. only this certificate will be considered and not certificates which might be installed on other servers etc.